# IE8 won't close window which opened windows with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'd like a PHP script to run that locates and opens results in new windows, then closes the original page that runs the script. Here is my script. It works great on IE 9+, but we cannot get it to work on IE 8. It seems as though the window.close is closing the "spawned" windows too?

```
<?php

$sn = $_GET['sn'];

$files = array();

$filepath = '/data/.../.../.../ABC';
$urlpath = 'http://AAA.slcusd.org';

$files = glob("$filepath/$sn*.pdf");

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";

foreach ($files as $fullfilename) {
  $filename = substr($fullfilename, 37, 20);
  echo "window.open('$urlpath/$filename','_blank');\n";
}

echo "window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();\n";

echo "</script>\n";

?>
```

Comment: This is a javascript issue, not PHP.

Comment: I think `window.open` is a lil deprecated, if i'm not lost in time, it's 2013 not 1999, so, `window.open` is a dirty work. I would recommend something like jQueryUI :)

Comment: @UltimateProgrammer_BR, `window.open()` is not deprecated and works fine.  jQuery UI has nothing to do with `window.open()`.  Not sure what you are getting at...

Comment: I was talking about the "spawn multiple windows" thing...

Comment: @UltimateProgrammer_BR You can't open windows with jQueryUI. I think you are mixing up browser windows with modal windows.

Comment: Yeah. Instead of a simple standards way of opening a window lets load a bloated library for no good reason @UltimateProgrammer_BR

Comment: I know, it depends of use. But browsers will not tolerate multiple windows spawn because of security reasons.

Comment: Why not just post to the results page?

Comment: @Javalsu I think because it is possibly returning more than one result. Could I post to the results page and also open other windows if needed <--other pages exist in search)?